# T-SQL creating simple cte error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I am trying to write a very simple CTE in T-SQL. Can you please tell me why I get an incorrect syntax error?

```
use AdventureWorks2012
go   

With employeecount_CTE ([MaritalStatus], totalemployees) as
(
     select 
         [MaritalStatus], count(*) as totalemployees
     from 
         [HumanResources].[Employee]
     group by 
         [MaritalStatus]
)
```

Comment: You never used the CTE, hence the error.

Comment: Learn how to ask good questions. You mentioned that you get an error - so why are you hiding the error message from everyone? That's important information that others need to see to understand your issue (generally speaking).

Comment: @SMor Why don't you test for yourself.  It does not throw an error message.

Answer (score 2):

Per the docs, "A CTE must be followed by a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement that references some or all the CTE columns."

This can be found at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql

So if you are not following up with one of these statements, then you will get an error. The following code should return the data from the CTE.

```
use AdventureWorks2012
go

With employeecount_CTE ([MaritalStatus], totalemployees) as
(
    select 
        [MaritalStatus], count(*) as totalemployees
    from 
        [HumanResources].[Employee]
    group by 
        [MaritalStatus]
)
select * 
from employeecount_CTE
```

Comment: Thank you very much - very simple explanation.  My source material had said that the cte CAN be referenced by SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE and not MUST be referenced